Huawei app crashed when launching after updating libraries
After updating some libraries my huawei app is crashing when launching. The splash screen is shown for 1 second and then the app stops.
I updated agconnect to the latest version (1.9.1.303) and my gradle version is 8.6.0.
And these are the logs:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lro/datakit/util/EventBus;
    at ro.base.architecture.activity.BaseActivity.Y2(SourceFile:8)
    at ro.base.architecture.activity.BaseActivity.A2(SourceFile:27)
    at ro.base.architecture.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:4)
    at ro.ui.auth.login.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:1)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ro.datakit.util.EventBus
    ... 19 more

Here are my libraries:
googleImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:6.7.0.300'
googleImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.6.1.301'

// huawei libs
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.9.1.303'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:base:6.2.0.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:hwid:6.12.0.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.12.0.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.7.0.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-crash:1.9.1.303'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:6.7.0.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.11.0.304'
huaweiImplementation 'dev.supasintatiyanupanwong.libraries.android.huawei.maps:maps-utils:1.0.0-alpha03'



allprojects {
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0'
            classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.18.0"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

            // Add the Firebase Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'

            classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.303'
            classpath 'com.huawei.hms.plugin:analytics:5.0.1.300'
        }
    }
}

Here is my EventBus class which you can see it's in the correct path.
package ro.datakit.util

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import ro.datakit.rest.response.auth.AuthorizeResponse

object EventBus {
    val BUS = MutableLiveData<AuthorizeResponse>()

    val LOGOUT_BUS = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
}

Also here is my build.gradle (:datakit)
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdk 34

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SHOW_CAN_NETWORK_CONSOLE", "false"
    }

    flavorDimensions "default", "services"

    productFlavors {
        live {
            dimension "default"
        }
        stage {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SHOW_CAN_NETWORK_CONSOLE", "true"
        }
        dev {
            dimension "default"
        }
        preprod {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SHOW_CAN_NETWORK_CONSOLE", "true"
        }
        google {
            dimension "services"

        }
        huawei {
            dimension "services"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.pro'
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {

        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
    lint {
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true
        quiet true
    }
    namespace 'ro.datakit'
}

dependencies {
    // kotlin
    api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.5'

    api project(':basic')
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = false
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


show log and exception

I added the logs

The error indicates that the EventBus class cannot be found at the specified path ro.datakit.util.EventBus. This could mean the class is either missing, misnamed, or not properly imported.

That's the strange thing, I haven't made any changes on that class. This issue started ocurring after updating the libraries.

I also updated my question and added EventBus class and the build.gradle (:datakit)

After hours of research I discovered that adding android.enableR8.fullMode=false to my  gradle.properties file solved the issue. No idea why, but maybe this will help someone.
